# New Python Install - Openpyxl won't import "Worksheet"

Tags: python, openpyxl

So I bought a new laptop and did a fresh install of python 3.7.3 through the installer for Windows 10.  Afterwards, I updated my pip and then used pip install for Openpyxl.  I tried running my code that works on other computers but on this setup, its giving me

`ImportError: cannot import name 'Worksheet' from 'openpyxl.worksheet' (C:\Users\James\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\__init__.py)`

Anyone have any idea why I would get this error?  This is the line of code for reference.

`from openpyxl.worksheet import Worksheet`

Comment: isn't it " from openpyl.workbook import Workbook "

Comment: @JoeA I have `from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook` before the line I posted above.

Comment: Try "from openpyxl import worksheet" (no quotes) It should import worksheet

Comment: the error you're seeing is because of capitalization of the 2nd "worksheet'.  use `from openpyxl.worksheet import worksheet"` (note all lowercase)

Comment: There is probably no need to do this because you should not be working directly with worksheets that are not part of a workbook.

Answer (score 3):

Expanded answer from my comment above:
*the error you're seeing is because of capitalization of the 2nd "worksheet'. use from openpyxl.worksheet import worksheet" (note all lowercase)*

the `Worksheet` class is buried under two levels of `worksheet`.  This is because the `openpyxl` package has ***a package and a module, both named `worksheet`***.  So to access it, use `from openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet import Worksheet`.

Of course, one could use `from openpyxl.worksheet import worksheet` but then will need to prepend `Worksheet` with `worksheet` everywhere in your code, like so: `worksheet.Worksheet`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is this new?  I haven't had a chance to try it yet because we started our work day so messing with code this early when we are prepping isn't possible.  Instead, I'm using my old machine that this code works perfectly fine on without any changes.  I will try this though in a few hours!

Comment: not sure, but could be if it worked for you earlier.  I only have the newer version.  you may want to peruse their [version history](https://pypi.org/project/openpyxl/#history) if you care to and have the time :).  post any revelations if you find any and mark/upvote the answer if you found it useful.

Comment: Well, this totally worked!  Thank you for the explanation because I definitely needed to do it as `from openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet import Worksheet` because the rest of the code references it that way.  I ran into some newer problems though, looks like our code needed some updating.

Answer (score 0):

I'm hoping this worked below:

```
from openpyxl import worksheet
```

I apologize I initially thought

`from openpyl.workbook import Workbook` might help